# Magento 2 + Migration from 1.7.0.2 Product view & category page giving 404 error

Tags: magento-1.7, magento2, migration, 404-page

I have Migrate magento 1.7.0.2 to Magento 2.
( I have migrate site in local using CMD)

I have face Product detail page & Category page is giving 404 page. search is working fine.

When i console i get this Error

#### "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/projectname/category"

Below are list of system exception getting in log file.

[2016-04-21 11:03:04] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []

[2016-04-21 11:03:04] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []

[2016-04-21 11:03:04] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []

[2016-04-21 11:03:04] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'paypal.partner.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []

[2016-04-21 11:03:04] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'bml.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []

[2016-04-21 11:03:04] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'store.settings.currency' tries to reorder itself towards 'store_language', but their parents are different: 'store.settings' and 'header.panel' respectively. [] []

Is there any way to solve this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: I have truncate **url_write**  table and now its working fine. but face another issue its not able to rebuilt.
and category url like this :-

http://localhost/projectname/catalog/category/view/s/designers/id/34/

And product page url like this :

http://localhost/projectname/catalog/product/view/id/1120/s/oushak-rug-red/category/34/ 

I need to make its accessible by relevant url.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I dont know its right approach or not but I have truncate **url_write** table and now its working fine. but face another issue its not able to rebuilt.